# How to substantiate that $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to substantiate that set is countable: Set $\mathbb{Z}^3$, consists of all triples $(a ,b, c)$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ – integers. 
My idea is this, but I am really not sure: We know that the $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of the integers and the set $\mathbb{Z}^3$ represents the set with basis or place $3$. An integer is positive if it is greater than zero and negative if it is less than zero. Zero is defined as neither negative nor positive. As given in question that a.b.c are integers , so it is proved that the following sets are countable.

Comment: What tools can you use? Do you know what a bijection is, and the fact that any set $X$ having a bijection $f:X\to\mathbb{N}$ is countable?

Comment: Why did you write all that stuff about positive and negative? What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: You have to prove that a set of 3 elements is countable? Isn't that self evident? Usually, countability turns up with infinite sets. Is it that you have to give a formal proof?

Comment: @Auclair No, the given set does not just have three elements.

Comment: @tobias kildetoft Woops, prior to the edit I thought he meant $Z_{3}$. The question makes more sense now. I'll concede it was a stupid misunderstanding, given that he specifies the elements as triples.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you one solution, assuming you know about bijections and cardinality.

We know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable, so there exists a bijection $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N}$.  But then, we automatically get that the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is the same as $\mathbb{N}^3$ through the bijection $g:\mathbb{Z}^3\to \mathbb{N}^3$ given by $$ g((a,b,c))=(f(a),f(b),f(c)) $$ (you can check yourself that $g$ is a bijection)

So all we have left to prove is that **$\mathbb{N}^3$ is countable** (since we just showed $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is the same size as $\mathbb{N}^3$)

---

To show $\mathbb{N}^3$ is countable, it is sufficient to show that

(1) $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable

(2) The product of $2$ countable sets is countable

This will finish the proof, since $\mathbb{N}^3 = \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, which is the same size as $(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})\times\mathbb{N}$ (this can be seen through the bijection $h((a,b,c))=((a,b),c)$ ).

So $(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})\times\mathbb{N}$ countable $\implies$ $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ countable $\implies$ $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ countable.

---

Proof of (1):

The function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ given by
$$ f(n) = (m,k) $$
is a bijection (check yourself using the fact that any natural number $n$ can be written uniquely as $n=2^{k-1}(2m-1)$ for $m,k\geq 1$).

---

Proof of (2):

Given $X$ and $Y$ are countable sets.  This means that there are bijections $f:X\to\mathbb{N}$ and $g:Y\to\mathbb{N}$.  Then we can easily verify that $h:X\times Y \to \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ defined by $$ h((x,y))=(f(x),g(y)) $$ is a bijection.  And by (1), this means $X\times Y$ is countable

Comment: It is beautifull, now I understand.

Comment: But how can I substantiate that sets are countable, if given is this: Set GRAPHS, consists of all graphs G with finite number of vertices. I have no idea

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, burying it as a comment to an answer is not what you should do. Instead, accept an answer for this question, and then post a new question.